# Why is NUMBER format lost in view when DISTINCT used in underlying view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I was trying to figure out why I lost my column number formats when selecting from a particular view (either to create another view or when copying the view to create a table), and was surprised to find that DISTINCT was the culprit.  Using the simplest view possible that illustrates the issue:

```
CREATE VIEW Test AS
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(1.5 AS  NUMBER(6,3)) AS TestCol from dual;

desc test;
TESTCOL NUMBER(6,3)

create view test2 as
select * from test;

desc test2;
TESTCOL NUMBER
```

However, if I also use DISTINCT when creating the secondary view, the number format is preserved:

```
create view test3 as
select DISTINCT * from test;

desc test3;
TESTCOL NUMBER(6,3)
```

The bigger problem for me was when using a copy command to generate a table from this view:

```
copy from bob/bob@localhost/ora create test4 using select * from test;

desc test4;
TESTCOL NUMBER(38)
```

And my number precision is lost:

```
select * from test4;

TESTCOL
2  -- should be 1.5
```

But if I also specify `DISTINCT` in the copy command, the numbers get copied properly.

The question is why does `DISTINCT` affect the number format in this way?  After an (admittedly quick) search, I couldn't find the reason for this, does anyone know?

Comment: What db version are you on? Is this the SQL*PLus copy command that you use (and what version of SQL*Plus in this case)? Do you observe the same behaviour with CTAS (CREATE TABLE AS SELECT) ?

Comment: I'm using 11g 11.2.0.1,  and have since found out that this problem is not present on 11.2.0.2 or 11.2.0.3  so I guess it must have been a bug that's been addressed.  CTAS has slightly different behaviour - the data type still shows up as just NUMBER but I don't lose the actual number - i.e. its 1.5 in the created table.